# how do I list all columns in all tables in all databases in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to make a list of all columns in all tables from all databases in my Hive.

I need a row like:

```
Database.table.column column_type comment
```

Obviously I can use

```
show databases;
```

and for each database I can use

```
show tables;
```

and for each table use:

```
describe table_name;
```

Obviously I could use Hive_metastore database that is somewhere in my Postgress database, but i have no accesss there.

But I'd like to have one bash script that would loop over databases->tables->columns and get the details.

I have started with generating a list of databases:

```
hive -e 'show databases;' | tee databases.txt
```

Than I was going to loop over the databases and make a list of tables:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat databases.txt`;
# w i mamy liste baz
  do
   hive -e 'show tables where database = $i;' | tee tables.txt

done
```

But I feel in guts that it's not the right way...
Can you help?

Regards 
Pawel

Comment: This is not a technical issue but an organizational one. Get access to the metastore, ask someone to query it for you, or ask for a dump that you can use locally.

Comment: This is strictly technical question. How do i access hive column list from a bash/hive level.

Comment: You aready aware of the technical options. Querying the metastore is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `hive -e 'show databases;'`; 
do
    echo $i;
    hive --database=$i -e 'show tables;' | tee -a output.txt;
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO. It is nice to give little explanation to your answer instead of giving only code block.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `show tables where database = $i`

With `use $i; show tables;`. And you should be using `tee -a`

But I agree, the metastore would be the best option here

Worth mentioning your UUOC

[Looping through the content of a file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)